# Django javascript not working $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, django, materialize

So, I've been working on a django project (using djagno 1.11) and I saw a really cool chat feature that someone mocked up (using django 2.0) [here](https://utopian.io/utopian-io/@ajmaln/part-1-creating-a-simple-chat-app-with-djangorestframework) with their git repo [here](https://github.com/ajmaln/DRF-Chat). I can recreate the entire project following the guide in its own app, but when I add it to my own I get into trouble. My current app uses bootstrap and has javascript to add items to cart and other such things and I wonder if that is getting in the way. That other javascript still works, the new javascript doesnt'. I get your basic error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

and when I google search it I see that this means that something is being used before it is defined. I'm decent at python, but an extreme novice at javascript and so I'm not sure what is happening. Diving into the error, I see the following:

```
    <script src="https://project.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/chat.js"></script>
<script>
    // For receiving
    sender_id = "";
    receiver_id = "1";

    //For sending
    $(function () {      <<--  This is where the error is pointing to.
        scrolltoend();
        $('#chat-box').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var message = $('#id_message');
            send('', '', message.val());
            message.val('');
        })
    })
</script>

</div>
```

The above code is at the bottom of an html file that lives in the project/chat/templates/chat/chat.html and it references chat.js via `{% static 'js/chat.js' %}` which above is the aws line of code which lives in the cloudhere: project/static_my_proj/js/chat.js. This code i'm integrating has stuff like 'materialize.js' and 'materialize.min.js' which I trying to understand what they do.

I wonder if I'm trying to combine two types of javascript. I'm completely lost. Does anyone have any pointers? Is there any code I can provide that would help?

Thanks

Comment: you have to define jquery, or if you did define, it's your js blocks order. Browser render's order is depends on html mark up's order.

Comment: I think your right. I did as Ahmet said below and the error technically went away, but now I'm calling jquery on each html page where I should probably have it in one spot. I'll need to look at js block order. I think js blocks come last and since this js is inside an html code block it is coming out of order.

Comment: i think you can do the following:
on your base.html(master page) you put your jquery and after it's script tag put {% block scripts %}{% endblock scripts %} and on child page put js function inside {% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}. PS: //it's just a brief explanation//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the following line

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

above / before

```
<script src="https://project.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/chat.js"></script>
```

this line

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't declare the variables correctly.

Variables,

```
sender_id = "";
receiver_id = "1";
```

should be declared like this,

```
var sender_id = "";
var receiver_id = "1";

// if you are using ES6 then

const sender_id="";
const receiver_id = "1";
```

Other than this, maybe you should include jquery as Ahmet Zeybek said.

Materialize.js and Materialize.css is the part of the materialize framework which is similar to bootstrap.

Comment: If your problem is solved then please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: So, the java script is actually in an html snippet of code and so sender and receiver are actually correct. I went and did Ahmet's suggestion and it fixes it.

Comment: great.. but, how is your code working, if you haven't declared your variables correctly ??